# How to set the window scroll position to the field to be validate, on button click if page is not valid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have many fields on the page that requires users to scroll the page upward/downward, and I have validation on every field, I am displaying errors on button click but is there a way that I can set the scroll position to the position at that field which requires validation on the page, so user knows that there are some errors?

I am using ASP.Net, and VB.Net

**Edit 01 :** I am using client side validation using 'RequiredFieldValidator' in aspx.

Comment: how are you validating the page? by using javascript or server side validations?

Comment: Check my edited question. Sorry about that

Comment: you can use SetFocusOnError = True of validator..

Comment: @SohailHameed Should I have to put in 

<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/TestMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    EnableEventValidation="true" CodeFile="MyTest.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyTest"
    MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" SetFocusOnError = True%>

Or should I put with every field?

Comment: no it is a property of validator. in every validator u need to set this property true.... but this might not work in few browsers.. so then u need a javascript method for this :) but first check that one

Comment: @SohailHameed Hey man. Thanks it works. Put your comments in Answer so that i can accept it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SetFocusOnError = True of validator..